# When other servers are normal, why one server kept reporting "data is not ready" in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask you guys a question about Apache IoTDB. An error was reported when using "select", saying that the data is not ready.

I think it may be because that the server has just started, but other databases already can query data. Also I have not seen the data after waiting for a long time. I would like to ask is it because this certain database server was broken? Or what should I do to solve this problem?